# problem materials effect

Tags: materials, unity

I have a problem, I explain you.

[image]

[image]

if you're looking my 2 pictures above:

First picture it's when I selected Wiewport shading solid

second picture it's when I selected Wiewport shading texture

when I export my object 3D to .FBX to use in unity 3D or I create a image in UV/Image editor and I save the image,

Blender always applies the rendering on the texture when you choose "Wiewport shading solid" and I don't like this rendering, I prefer "shading texture" because it has a little cartoon effect.

How to do to export the materials with shading texture effect?

Thanks for your help?

Comment: I dont know what the result will be in Unity, but have you tried to set it shadeless (you can find that in the shading region of the material panel) ?

Comment: There's no way to choose which shading to use for baking; instead test it in Rendered shading (or in-game one) and estimate how it looks like. As for your desired result - probably you might want to make material shadeless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)